# How to modify a PHP variable everytime AJAX is called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to loadmore data from an image gallery.

I pass PHP variable to set the $page number and other data.  Each time I loadmore data from AJAX, I would like the $page to increase by 1 so next time, it gets the next data on the list.  Here is my JS

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#postswrapper').offset().top + $('#postswrapper').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {


    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "loadmore.php",
        method: "get",
        data: { page: "<?=$page?>", perpage: "<?=$perpage?>"},
        success: function(html)
                {
                    if(html)
                    {
                        $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();

                        // ###### THIS IS NOT WORKING 
                        <? $page++; ?>

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                    }

                }

    }); // close AJAX

}  // close if()
}); // close $(window)
```

I tried incorporating `<? $page++; ?>` in the success function, but it's not working.

I USE THE `$page` variable inside my SQL query

HERE IS MY loadmore.php CODE

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) 
{
   $page = $_GET['page'];  
   $perpage = $_GET['perpage']; 
   $start = ($page -1) * $perpage ;

   $sql = mysql_query("select * from ..... limit ".$start.", ".$perpage." ");

   $html = '';

    while($blog2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{  
    $html .='HTML GOES HERE';
 }  

echo $html;
exit;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to load the SQL query starting from the next page every time I load more data...  Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Comment: PHP script doesn't remember anything. Either use sessions or send page number every ajax request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remember to sanitize any user input in your PHP file to prevent sql injection:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$perpage = $_GET['perpage'];

// escape the values, or make sure they are numbers, e.g.:
if(!is_numeric($page))
  $page = 0;
if(!is_numeric($perpage))
  $perpage = 10; // or whatever default value
```

And write your PHP values into Javascript variables and use those in your js code:

```
var pageNumber = <?= $page ?>;
var perPage = <?= $perpage ?>;

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#postswrapper').offset().top + $('#postswrapper').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {


    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "loadmore.php",
        method: "get",
        data: { page: pageNumber, perpage: perPage},
        success: function(html)
                {
                    if(html)
                    {
                        $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();

                        // use the js variable
                        pageNumber++;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                    }

                }

    }); // close AJAX

}  // close if()
}); // close $(window)
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**

PHP runs server-side, the AJAX runs client side.  You need a javascript variable there (although you can set its initial value with PHP).

Comment: so if I define: `var page = 1;` 

my ajax data should be like this: `data: { page: page, perpage: "<?=$perpage?>", search: "<?=$search?>", blogtag: "<?=$blogtag?>"},`  ?

Comment: Essentially yes.  Unless those other terms are ones that can be modified on the client end as well.  You'd also want the `page` variable to exist outside the function.